# Plotting worldwide COVID-19 evolution as lines using python (matplotlib, seaborn or plotly)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plotly

As an exercise, I’m trying to plot the excellent [COVID-19 data provided by Johns Hopkins CSSE](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv).
I’m confused because the time series is organized in columns (each day is put to the side of the other... see below in the figure). Preferentially I’d like to avoid transposing the columns to lines and vice-versa. My intention is to plot the COVID-19 evolution as lines for all countries, day by day (yes, it is going to get messy).

I was thinking that I could use a for loop iterating through the columns to populate a list and use this as my y-axis but do we have a more “direct” way to get this plot? Recently I'm using Plotly more, but I'm OK with matplotlib or seaborn too.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this particular dataset is very well suited for the long data format preferred by plotly.express. Particularly because of the many missing observations for `Province / State`. And since your intention is to

> plot the COVID-19 evolution as lines for all countries, day by day

...there's no need for `Province / State`, `Lat` or `Lon`. So I would just sum the data per country, and use `go.Scatter` traces for each country. And no, it's not going to get too messy since you can easily select traces or focus on different parts of the chars since we're applying the magnificent powers of plotly here. Anyway, I hope the setup will meet your preferences. Don't hesitate to let me know if there's anything else you need.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Plot, zoomed:**

[image]

**EDIT - Version 2:** Development by days from first occurence

One way to make the plot a bit lesss messy, is to measure the development from day one of the first occurence for each area like this:

[image]

In order to produce the first plot, just copy the data in your link and store it as `covid.csv` in a folder named `c:\data`.

**Complete code for the first plot:**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

dfi = pd.read_csv(r'C:\data\covid.csv',sep = ",", header = 0)

# drop province, latitude and longitude
df = dfi.drop(['Province/State', 'Lat', 'Long'], axis = 1)

# group by countries
df_gr = df.groupby('Country/Region').sum()#.reset_index()

time = df_gr.columns.tolist()
df_gr.columns = pd.to_datetime(time)
df_gr.reset_index(inplace = True)

# transpose df to get dates as a row index
df = df_gr.T

# set first row as header
new_header = df.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:] #take the data less the header row
df.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header

# order df columns descending by country with most cases
df_current = df.iloc[-1].to_frame().reset_index()
df_sort = df_current.sort_values(df_current.columns[-1], ascending = False)# plotly setup
order =  df_sort['Country/Region'].tolist()
df = df[order]

fig = go.Figure()

# add trace for each country
for col in df.columns:
    #print(col)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[col].values, name=col))
fig.show()
```

**Code for the last plot:**

*This builds on the df from code snippet 1:*

```
# replace leading zeros with nans
df2= df.replace({'0':np.nan, 0:np.nan})

# shift leading nans, leaving
# nans in the last rows for some
# regions
df2=df2.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-x.isna().sum()))
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2=df2.drop('index', axis = 1)

fig2 = go.Figure()

# add trace for each country
for col in df2.columns:
    fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2.index, y=df2[col].values
                              , name=col
                             ))
fig2.update_layout(showlegend=True)
fig2.update_layout(xaxis=dict(title='Days from first occurence'))
fig2.show()
```

Comment: Dear @vestland, thank you for your answer. That is exactly what I wanted and I'm happy to see that somehow I was going in the right direction. Thanks for taking the time to take a look at this, it was extremely helpful.

Comment: @HenriqueJunior Happy to help! You could always try changing the theme of the plot to make it a bit more exciting. Plotly_dark is always a winner. Perhaps even annotate the ten countries with the most cases to spice it up even more.

Answer (score 1):

plotly works with tidy data which would require you to convert the dates into a single column.  I would use pandas melt to convert the date columns into a single column and then plot.  From my experience with plotly its been best to learn how plotly likes the data structured (tidy dataframes) and get my datasets into that form as opposed to trying to create the datasets in another way.

I think if your data is as simple as is shown in the picture the following would get it into the correct form:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Country/Region'])
```

More info on how plotly likes data here https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/

More info on pandas melt here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html